# Animation with clip-path: inset doesn't work in Safari

Tags: css, safari, clip-path

I animated a clip-path that works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but Safari completely ignores the animation. After testing, I found my static clip-paths works fine in Safari, but it refuses to animate it. Here is my css:

```
.home .arc-line img {
    -webkit-animation-name: mobile-arc;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mobile-arc {
  0% { -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0); }
  80% { -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0); }
  100% { -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0); }
}
```

It is on the mobile-version (screen width of 400px) of the landing page of the following website: [www.satya-ame-art.com](https://satya-ame-art.com)
It is the white arc-line in the center of the page, that supposed to animate from left to right, but remains static on Safari.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Works for me on Safari 12.1 (note that animation doesn't need -webkit- prefix anymore (clip-path still does).

Comment: How strange... I'm running Safari 12.0 on a virtual machine of Mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Ok, having found no way to fix the bug, the only workaround I figured out was to abandon the animated clip-path idea and replace it with an inline SVG, animated thanks to the ["Animate Calligraphy with SVG"](https://css-tricks.com/animate-calligraphy-with-svg/) technique.

It was much more work, but the result was visually identical, if not better.